# CSS assets compiling to a single "application.css" in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `config.assets.debug = true` in development.

According to the Asset Pipeline docs (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) this should generate seperate HTML tags for each of the files specified in my manifest (`application.css`).

My manifest at the moment is simply including two css files from its directory (`products.css` and `articles.css`):

```
/*
 *= require products
 *= require articles */
```

Instead of getting two `<link>` tags for each file I am getting the following in my HTML:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.debug.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload">`

Why is this merging into one file happening in development with `config.assets.debug = true`?

I also don't really understand the merged file. It contains the following where `from-articles` and `from-products` are two css declarations in `articles.css` and `products.css` respectively. :

```
/* line 1, app/assets/stylesheets/products.scss */
.from-products {
  color: red;
}
/* line 1, app/assets/stylesheets/articles.scss */
.from-articles {
  color: burlywood;
}
/*


 */

/*# sourceMappingURL=application.css-725e6da4bfd4669b7236c1af7a60f92d7a11f4813ed6b45c0439c1c7f337bd4e.map */
```